# Subversion Tag Fill Automatic Update on Linux

Tags: java, linux, svn

Can someone please tell me how to get Subversion Tag Fill Automatic Update on linux..

Inside JavaDoc section you write:

```
/**
 * @version $Date$ $Author$
 */
```

How can I tell my svn client to Automatic fill $Author$ and $Date$ on Linux..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html):

> Simply adding keyword anchor text to your file does nothing special. Subversion will never attempt to perform textual substitutions on your file contents unless explicitly asked to do so [...]  The svn:keywords property, when set on a versioned file, controls which keywords will be substituted on that file

And they give an example with the keywords that you want:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Date Author" YOURFILE
```

Don't forget to commit after setting properties.